# How to change the value within function, then apply it to while loop?

Tags: python

So I have this function:

```
def check_List(listname, input_num):
    if input_num in listname:
        print('Duplicated Number')
        input_num=0
        return input_num
```

the purpose was to change whatever I input for input_num to become 0 if it's a duplicate in a list and it worked. However, I have a while loop statement that states if the input is less than 1 or greater than 9, it will go into a loop. When I place this fuction into the loop, it does mention that it is a duplicate, but it will keep the original value that was input.

Here's my full code:

```
guess=[]

while guess != rnd:
    count=0
    strike=0
    ball=0
    
    guess1=int(input("Input First Number: "))
    while guess1>9 or guess1<1:
        print('Input a number between 1-9')
        guess1=int(input("Input First Number: "))
    guess.append(guess1)

    guess2=int(input('Input Second number: '))
    check_List(guess,guess2)
    print(guess2)
    while guess2>9 or guess2<1:
        print('Input a number between 1-9')
        guess2=int(input("Input Second Number: "))
    
    guess.append(guess2)


    guess3=int(input('Input Thrid number: '))
    while guess3>9 or guess3<1:
        print('Input a number between 1-9')
        guess3=int(input("Input Thrid Number: "))
    guess.append(guess3)

    guess4=int(input('Input Fourth number: '))
    while guess4>9 or guess4<1:
        print('Input a number between 1-9')
        guess4=int(input("Input Fourth Number: "))
    guess.append(guess4)
    print(guess, rnd)
```

Comment: Where does the variable `rnd` came from? Please fix all of your code indentation

Comment: Creating a [mre] will help us to focus on the real problem. Also, on the way of creating one, you might even solve the problem yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinkt the behavior you observe might be liked to the fact, that you use `check_List` only on one input. I propose to clean up the code a little:

```
counting= ['first', 'second', 'third','fourth']
guess = []
while len(guess) < 4:
    c_guess = int(input(f"Input {counting[len(guess)]} Number: "))
   
    if c_guess in guess:
        print('Duplicated Number')
        continue
    
    if 9 > c_guess >= 1:
        guess.append(c_guess)
        continue
    
    print('Input a number between 1-9')
```

You can further improve it by cathing bad(non integer) inputs:

```
try:
    c_guess = int(input(f"Input {counting[len(guess)]} Number: "))
except:
    print('Not a valid integer number.')
```